# Let $a, n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}.$ Prove that the product $(a+1) \cdots (a+n)$ is divisible by $n!$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

Let $a, n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}.$ Prove that the product $(a+1)\cdots(a+n)$ is divisible by $n!$.

I think that can be done using the rule that ${a+n \choose n}= \dfrac {(a+n)!} {(a+n-n)! (n)!} $, however even when doing this I can't determine how to show it is divisible by n!.

Answer (score 1):

We can write $$\displaystyle (a+1)(a+2).......(a+n) = \frac{a!\times (a+1)(a+2)...(a+n)}{a!} = \frac{(a+n)!}{a!}$$

So $$\displaystyle \frac{(a+n)!}{a!} = \frac{(a+n)!}{a!\times n!}\times n! = \underbrace{\binom{a+n}{n}}_{\bf{Integer\; Quantity}}\times n!$$

So $$\displaystyle (a+1)(a+2).......(a+n) = \frac{(a+n)!}{a!\times n!}\times n! = \underbrace{\binom{a+n}{n}}_{\bf{Integer\; Quantity}}\times n!$$ is divisible by $n!$

Answer (score 0):

Well if you know that ${a+n \choose n}$ is an integer (and it is, binomial coefficients are alwyas integers), then it follow easily; in fact your product is precisely $\displaystyle \frac {(a+n)!}{a!}$

Answer (score 0):

You're already almost done. You only need to note that $(a + 1) \ldots (a + n) = \frac{(a + n)!}{a!}$.