# Prove that $(a+1)(a+2)(a+3)\cdots(a+n)$ is divisible by $n!$

Tags: proof-writing, factorial

so I have this math problem, I have to prove that $$(a+1)(a+2)(a+3)\cdots(a+n)\text{ is divisible by }n!$$ I'm not sure how to start this problem... I completely lost. Here's what I know: $(a+1)(a+2)(a+3)\cdots(a+n)$ is like a factorial in that we are multiplying consecutive terms, $n$ times. However, how would I prove that it is divisible by $n$? Thanks

Comment: Hint: think about the binomial coefficient ${a+n\choose n}$

Comment: @JulianRosen, it's = $\begin{pmatrix}a\\n-1\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}a\\n\end{pmatrix}$, Pascal's relation right?

Comment: Not quite, ${a\choose n-1} + {a\choose n}={a+1\choose n}$, but that isn't what I was hinting at. Write out ${a+n\choose n}$ in terms of factorials.

Comment: @KFC just write the explicit formula:
$$
\binom{a+n}{n} = \frac{(a+n)!}{a!n!}
$$
and, of course, this coefficient is an *integer*.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom thanks

Comment: See the answers here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1446786/let-a-n-in-mathbbz-geq-0-prove-that-the-product-a1-cdots-an

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let
$$ f(a,n) = (a+1)(a+2)\cdot\ldots\cdot(a+n).\tag{1}$$
We have:
$$ f(a+1,n)-f(a,n) = n\cdot f(a+1,n-1) \tag{2} $$
hence the claim follows by applying a double induction.

Answer (score 1):

$$(a+1)(a+2)\dots(a+n) = \frac{(a+n)!}{a!}$$

We know $$\frac{(a+n)!}{(a!)(n!)} = {a+n\choose n} \in \mathbb{N}$$

So, $n!$ divides $\frac{(a+n)!}{a!} = (a+1)(a+2)\dots(a+n)$